# Change the type of a variable everywhere in the workspace

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I have a variable that is of a certain type (`TreeViewer`). I decided that I would now like this to be a different type (`TableViewer`).

This variable is mentioned in a lot of places and I would like to change it to a different type (`TableViewer`) in a lot of places.

Is there a quick way to do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know its not possible in Eclipse.
You can rename a variable by pressing Alt+Shift+R and all its references will be updated.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Thanks but it is not helpful unless you know with certainty that it is not possible.